# Не строит дерево категорий

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема при выборе дерева категорий.
Вот запрос, который я посылаю.

```
SELECT DISTINCT category.id, category.parent_id, category.name 
FROM category 
    JOIN category_closure ON category.id = category_closure.descendant 
WHERE category_closure.ancestor > 1;
```

Данный запрос работает только в Mysql 5.7, а в Mysql 5.6 не работает.
Обновить Mysql не вариант
[Ответ Mysql 5.7](https://yadi.sk/d/uWRgO3Uk3DMvRt)
[Ответ Mysql 5.6](https://yadi.sk/d/ere86q5J3DMuir)
[База](https://yadi.sk/d/yrbNNpLD3DMchQ)

Comment: А какой ответ сервера MySQL на 5.6?

Comment: Срабатывает как обычный select без join

Comment: А можно без скачивания файлов с ЯД структуру таблиц увидеть?

Comment: Может такой вариант? http://pastebin.com/MEr7E9eu

Comment: Согласен с @vp_arth, желательно и использовать подобный сервис: http://pastebin.com/ или допустим https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Результат такой же

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Nicholas122/7aa7916dc1744679cd45442a7c066af8

Comment: Странная реализация категорий... `category_closure` - это типа матрица смежности?

Comment: По сути да..... Я использовал Gedmo tree bundle https://github.com/malarzm/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md

Answer (score 1):

Ваш запрос(в основном из-за `DISTINCT`) ничем не отличается от:

```
SELECT category.id, category.parent_id, category.name 
FROM category 
WHERE category.id > 1
```

Comment: Вся соль в том, что мой запрос работает на mysql5.7, а ваш запрос сработал так же, как и мой на mysql5.6.То есть join не делает то, что должен сделать, потому на 5.6 мой запрос срабатывает как обычный селект

Comment: Сколько строк вы получаете в результате в 5.7? Не 44?

Comment: Да, 44 и в 5.6 тоже 44, но они в другом порядке

Comment: Вот такой должен быть порядок:
parent 1
children 1
children 1
parent 2
children 2
parent 3
children 3
chidlren 3

Comment: О каком порядке идёт речь, если `ORDER BY` отсутствует?

Comment: @vp_arth, в `category_closure` всегда есть строчка, где `ancestor=descendant`, поэтому результаты одинаковы, без `distinct` появились бы дубликаты, относящиеся к другим `ancestor`